# How to style antd Table pagination property in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs, pagination, styles, antd

I'm using antd Table to display my data. so here i'm adding its pagination property, but it seems not aligned properly so i'm planning to add stlyes into it.

```
                          <Table
                            className="table product-overview"
                            columns={columns}
                            dataSource={dataSourceitems}
                            pagination={{className: "pagination", defaultPageSize: 5, showSizeChanger: true, pageSizeOptions: ['5','10']}}
                            responsive
                         >
```

Here, by that pagination class i can add styles but i couldn't add any style for the components inside.Beacuase actually it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPdiy.png) . Please someone help me to give a basic style like [thiss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dsbd.png)

Comment: Did you import the antd style in the file importing Table component? `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
` in `index.js` in the root.

Comment: Not yet @ChrisSu

Answer (score 0):

The CSS styles of antd components are separated from its components, so you also have to import antd css file at the same time, but you need only import it once, normally you can import it at two place:

### 1. src/index.js

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`

### 2. src/App.css

`@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`

You can check the guidance [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Install-and-Initialization)